# count items inside each of distinct status

Tags: mysql

Table `abc` - suppose there are three columns: `id`, `title` and `status`

```
select distinct status from abc;
```

Result:

```
home
archive
wait
aauth
impress

select count(distinct status) from abc;
```

Result: `5`

What I need is to count items inside each distinct status:

```
home       10
archive    14
wait       17
aauth      19
impress    27
```

Any help?

Comment: What is the table structure ? How do we know about items - which column(s) represent them ?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as `php`? Please remove that tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`GROUP BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp):

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM abc GROUP BY status;
```

Comment: @puerto you should check the answer as accepted in case someone else will looking for the same question

Comment: @puerto oh right, can't get to use to it with that answer accepting delay